# Whatsapp API error during sending an created template

Tags: whatsapp

```
{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
 "to": "91********5", 
 "type": "template", 
 "template": {
      "name": "demo_template",
      "language": {
           "code": "en_US" 
           }
            }
             }
```

This is passed as a post method.

`demo_template` is an existing template created by me.

Getting error like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#132012) Parameter format does not match format in the created template",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 132012,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "details": "header: Format mismatch, expected IMAGE, received UNKNOWN"
        },
        "error_subcode": 2494073,
        "fbtrace_id": "ARtWScjGa0rADjfHvbOH4bS"
    }
}
```

Comment: how you configured the template? what are the parameters and sections?

Comment: My template have one image on header and two strings on body. Plz give me the json syntax to call the template correctly

Comment: Follow the documentation, here is [the syntax](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates#media-based) for your requirement.

Comment: @SSANTOSH did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

For image you have to first upload the image in media library then you can get id for the media you have uploded then you can attach that id with the messaging template you send out in headers in your case it is image.[check this link here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates#media-based)

or you can directly use url link to attach media.`{ "type": "header", "parameters": [ { "type": "image", "image": { "link": "https://URL" } } ] },`

Answer (score 0):

{
"error": {
"message": "(#132001) Template name does not exist in the translation",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 132001,
"error_data": {
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"details": "template name (button_message) does not exist in en_US"
},
"fbtrace_id": "AdvIOb-7c4hj8yFuvkAvWjW"
}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).